# Validando DropDownList vazio

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownList("HorasPendenciaID", null, new { @class = "dropdown-custom" })
```

Quando seto '**0**' no seu ***value*** ele fica vazio. Gostaria de validar se o DropDown está com o valor zero ou não e exibir uma mensagem obrigando o usuário a selecionar algum valor. O devo fazer?

Comment: `HorasPendenciaID` é uma propriedade do seu *Model*?

Comment: Sim, é um atributo inteiro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O que devo fazer?

Marcar a propriedade do *Model* com [`[Required]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[Required]
public int HorasPendenciaID { get; set; }
```

Se as mensagens de validação ficarem em inglês, [instale este pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.pt-br/).